# What is the best way to store high quality images?

Tags: angular, mongodb, image, storage

I am currently using a mongo database where I am storing some quite large images in base 64 format ie: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQA... among some other data. The issue I am having is that since these images are quite large it is causing some queries, find all for example, to take about 11 seconds for only ~30 documents in the collection to be returned. I believe this is because the base 64 image string is so large.

I have tried compressing the images, but they lose quality if I do this. I've tried resizing the dimensions which also results in some quality loss when the image is zoomed in a bit on screen. I have also tried cropping the images but that doesn't reduce the size much since I don't want to crop a lot.

On my mongo database I also have a few indexes set up on the documents id and also on one field.

Is there any way I can store high quality images and maintain the quality while having reduced query times?

Answer (score 0):

My best advise to you is to store the files locally on the hosting server, and in the DB, store the name of the file and the user id / path to its files.

If you really want to save more, i'd do the following: If these are images, user can upload an image in the size of (for example): 4000X1500. You can use PHP (or any other server side language) to create a copy of the file with less pixels, thus, decreasing its size. It will save bandwidth and space / loading time (Good for SEO as well). So simply make a copy of the original version with a smaller size. On that note, PHP allows you, when copying an image to a smaller dimensions, to change the quality as well (between 1-100%).